# Does copper mesh react with wood?

Tags: wood, metal, copper, corrosion, wood-filler

I have about a quarter-sized hole in my door frame from where the bolt used to go, with a bigger hollow void behind it - and I want to fill this hole.  I was contemplating using some copper mesh I had to stuff the hole before using wood filler.

Does copper mesh react with wood in any way over the long run - enough for me to not use it?

Comment: I would use some automotive body filler.

Comment: A quarter-sized hole? A quarter of what? Maybe a coin, but the rest of the world may well not know how big that is!

Comment: @Tim Cheeky fellow :) Per the U.S. Mint, a quarter is: 0.955 in. or 24.26 mm.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - surprise surprise, there are other currencies around the world, we don't all handle US! But, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Copper won't react with wood normally, only maybe when it's permanently damp. But if you use filler, and cover it completely, water's not going to get in. If the mesh has small enough holes so the filler doesn't fall through, it's good to go.

Answer (score 1):

So I would drill a hole, or at least make the existing hole round to a suitable diameter like 1/2" or 3/4".

Then I would get a suitable dowel and glue that in place. That will give a stronger repair than copper mesh etc.

it can then be sanded, treated and finished as needed.